# How do I reveal the break icons upon the line numbers?

Tags: xcode6

The following image shows a break icon displayed upon a row number (Xcode 5.1.1):

[image]

I notice with Xcode 6 (Version 6.0 (6A279r)) that they don't appear:
[image]

How to I get the break icons to re-appear upon the row numbers as usual?

...or perhaps this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I apparently cleared it up by re-launching Xcode 6 and doing a complete cleansing.
Now I see the break points upon the line numbers.

The incident appears to be a bug; and I shall report it, if I can reproduce it.